# JSON request errors Mollybet API

Tags: c#, json, rest, unicode, django-rest-framework

We are experiencing problems in section 4.3.1   Create a new bet placement order with API https://api.mollybet.com/docs/v1/#create-a-new-bet-placement-order.

The client used is c# Httpclient,  and we are sending the parameters as JSON body.

```
{
   "betslip_id":"aff87f1773774ef7b04e81992c038e8f",
   "price":"2.06",
   "stake":"[\"EUR\", 13]",
   "duration":"15",
   "accounts":"[\"ibc\", \"_99899bb2_\"]",
   "adaptive_bookies":"[ibc]",
   "ignore_system_maintenance":false,
   "no_put_offer_exchange":false,
   "bookie_min_stakes":"{}",
   "user_data":null
}
```

validation_errors

Please refer to screenshots:
[image]

[image]

We are unable to get past this step, any advice would be much appreciated.

EDIT - CODE THAT GENERATES JSON AS REQUESTED BY dbc :

```
    private void doPlace(string betSlipId,double price , double stake , string bookie, string accountName)
    {
        try
        {
            //string placebetLink = "https://pro.sportmarket.com/trade/place_order";
            //var postData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            //{
            //    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("betslip_id",betSlipId),
            //    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("price" , price.ToString()),
            //    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("request_uuid",getRandom()),
            //    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("timeout","20"),
            //    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("stake",stake.ToString()),
            //    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("accounts",accountName),
            //    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("adaptive",bookie),
            //    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ignore_autoplacing","false"),
            //    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("csrfmiddlewaretoken", csrToken)
            //});

            //HttpResponseMessage placeResponse = httpClient.PostAsync(placebetLink, postData).Result;
            //placeResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            //string content = placeResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            //ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
            string stakeStr = string.Format("[\"EUR\", {0}]", stake);
            string placebetUrl = string.Format("{0}v1/orders/", endPonit);
            //var postData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            //{
            //    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("betslip_id",betSlipId),
            //    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("price" , price.ToString()),
            //    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("stake",stakeStr),
            //    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("duration","15"),
            //    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("accounts",accountName),
            //    new KeyValuePair<string,string>("adaptive_bookies",string.Format("[{0}]",bookie)),
            //    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ignore_system_maintenance","false"),
            //    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("no_put_offer_exchange","false"),
            //    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("bookie_min_stakes","{}"),
            //    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user_data","")

            //});

            PlaceRequest requestJson = new PlaceRequest();
            requestJson.betslip_id = betSlipId;
            requestJson.price = price.ToString();
            requestJson.stake = stakeStr;
            requestJson.accounts = accountName;
            requestJson.duration = "15";
            requestJson.adaptive_bookies = string.Format("[{0}]", bookie);
            requestJson.ignore_system_maintenance = false;
            requestJson.no_put_offer_exchange = false;
            requestJson.bookie_min_stakes = "{}";

            string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestJson);

            HttpResponseMessage placeResponse = ApiClient.PostAsync(placebetUrl, new StringContent(jsonStr, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
            placeResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            string content = placeResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: **user_data [ string ] (optional)** is one issue. You're passing it `null` which is not a string, try passing `"user_data":""` instead.

Comment: I think you just need to look at the API doc in more detail. For example, the JSON value **["EUR", 100]** represents the amount of one hundred euros. You have backslashes and quotes in your string **"stake":"[\"EUR\", 13]"** which it appears to be complaining about

Comment: if you upload your images via the stack overflow imgur we can embed the images into your question

Comment: `"[\"EUR\", 13]"` and `"[\"ibc\", \"_99899bb2_\"]"` are double-serialized -- i.e. they were arrays that were serialized to JSON strings, then those strings embedded in some larger object when was then serialized, causing the arrays to get serialized twice.  Is this what you meant to do?  Can you please share the code that generates this JSON, i.e. a [mcve]?

Comment: @dbc We are still experiencing the same issue, I have provided the code that generates the json.

Comment: This looks wrong, you probably want quotes after [   "adaptive_bookies":"[ibc]",